# How do I change where windows 8.1 stores files by default?

Tags: windows-8.1, filesystems, default-settings

So my C:\ drive is almost full, because of games. I noticed that a ton of the save data was there. I have also heard that you could either redirect or completely change the default save directory.
So say I had a Z:\ drive, it had 1 TB of storage left, the C:\ drive had 10 GB. So I would want to move the contents of the C:\ drive's Documents folder to Z:\ drive's Saves folder. And then make the Saves folder the default save location, instead of the Documents folder. So can I do it, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Physcogeek has correct advice, to just organize things yourself, this is the answer to your question:

**To redirect a folder to a new location**

1. Open explorer then right click on "Documents" or "Downloads" or any
   user folder, then select properties
2. Click the Location tab, and then click Move
3. Just change `C:\` to `Z:\`

[image]

You also might be prompted with a notification like this, just select yes.

[image]

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/redirect-folder-new-location#1TC=windows-7)
[Source 2](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-2024314/redirect-folders-drives-windows-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Only advice, ignore all the "my-junk" stuff and create your own proper folder layouts that have proper sub-folders all organised, on the disk you prefer to have it saved.
 First create a backup,
Then  manually move the stuff organised into the sub-folders from any of the other locations.
Then create a backup of your organised data

Word Documents
-    Personal
 -   Business
  -  Drafts
- Letters

(or any other proper organisation on your "data" disk)

WHY?
While you can set the location of the folders (just Drag n' Drop)  it still does not solution all the problems that could happen. Those folders not being any form of organisation to begin with. It does not solve when the disk is removed (the system and data disks are seperated). It does not help in the user understanding where stuff is actually located. the location is stored in registry, a proper registry backup reverted to a previous time would not have the location set.
There are other issues people have had through the ages, from viruses infecting specific users folders (but not going for thier data disk), to Upgrades to new systems being confused as to the location of the data.  IMO (and it is my opinion) it has never been worth it to the users, or to the people trying to help them, to have them change the stupid linked junk, that is not needed by anyone who does organise.

Make also a Downloads folder (I call incomming instead to not confuse) and start using save-as and selecting a more proper organised file locations for any and all saves.
While MS may have created a nice bucket to thrash all "your_stuff" into blindly, it is easy and more organised to completely Ignore those locations, or only use them when you must, and instead use your own methods.  And to keep your data on a seperated disk, and both the system disk and the data disk backed up.

There are now no links to break, you have to know where things are going, they are now finnaly organised, they can be on a different disk, the system itself is not changed in a way that it backfires, and you have to ask more questions.
Create your own destiny , not microsofts.